# Flutter tabbar wrap on overflow

Tags: flutter

When tabbar overflows, it gets clipped off. When scrolling is turned on we can scroll - `isScrollable: true,`.

I would like to know how do we wrap the `tabbar` on next line when width of screen is smaller. I would like some of the tabs to go on next line when available width is smaller.

This is useful on web where flutter webpage is seen on wide screen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Wrap` widget?

```dart
Column(
    children: [
      Wrap(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 4'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 5'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 6'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: TabBarView(
          children: [
            // tab views here
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Comment: It did not work